# Proof in logic that $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $ (P \lor Q) \rightarrow (P \land Q)$

Tags: logic

How is it possible to prove that  $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $ (P \lor Q) \rightarrow (P \land Q)$ using logic laws?

Comment: Use the answer to your previous question...

Comment: How would I use the the Ditributive property of truth - functional connectives?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can rewrite $(P∨Q)→(P∧Q)$ as $\lnot (P∨Q)∨(P∧Q)$.

Then use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), i.e. : $¬(P∨Q)$ is equivalent to $(¬P∧¬Q)$ to get :

$(¬P∧¬Q)∨(P∧Q)$.

Then you need the [Ditributive property of truth functional connectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) to transform the last formula into :

$[(¬P∧¬Q) \lor P] \land [(¬P∧¬Q) \lor Q]$

and applaing it again :

$(\lnot P \lor P ) \land (\lnot Q \lor P) \land (\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor Q)$.

Finally, we use the *Identity laws* : $\lnot P \lor P \equiv T$ and $T \land P \equiv P$, to simplify the formula and get :

> $(\lnot Q \lor P) \land (\lnot P \lor Q)$.

But this is : $P \leftrightarrow Q$.

*Note*

You can find a useful summary of the main concepts and of the laws involved in the proof above into this [presentation](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dmmr/slides/Ch1a.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $P\Rightarrow Q, Q\Rightarrow P \dashv\vdash (P\lor Q)\Rightarrow (P\land Q)$ by showing first that $P\Rightarrow Q, Q\Rightarrow P \vdash (P\lor Q) \Rightarrow (P\land Q)$ and then that $(P\lor Q) \Rightarrow (P\land Q)\vdash (P\Rightarrow Q) \land (Q\Rightarrow P)$:

[image: $P\Rightarrow Q, Q\Rightarrow P \vdash (P\lor Q) \Rightarrow (P\land Q)$]

[image: $(P\lor Q) \Rightarrow (P\land Q)\vdash (P\Rightarrow Q) \land (Q\Rightarrow P)$]